# how to achieve LinearLayout like layout in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-linearlayout, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter how to achieve Linear Layout like layout in flutter ? layout view's horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should try to understand Linear layout in flutter link is given below.

> https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-linearlayout

After that you will be able to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

`Row` is the horizontal  Linear Layout

```
new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
   ///display children in a horizontal manner
  ],
```

And `Column` is the vertical Linear Layout

```
new Column (
  children: <Widget>[
   ///display children in a vertical manner 
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve pure linear layout in flutter , use row widget while managing the main axis and cross axis alignment

**Example**

Lets say you want to show two icons horizontally with equal weight ie 1-1 each
Use row like this

```
Container(
            color: Colors.yellowAccent,
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                new Icon(
                  Icons.access_time,
                  size: 50.0,
                ),
                new Icon(
                  Icons.pie_chart,
                  size: 100.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

[image]